# Python classes - run method when any other method is called

Tags: python

I am writing a Python app which will use a config file, so I am delegating the control of the config file to a dedicated module, `configmanager`, and within it a class, `ConfigManager`.

Whenever a method within `ConfigManager` is run, which will change my config file in some way, I will need to get the latest version of the file from the disk. Of course, in the spirit of DRY, I should delegate the opening of the config file to it's own function.

However, I feel as though explicitly calling a method to get and return the config file in each function that edits it is not very "clean".

Is there a recommended way in Python to run a method, and make a value available to other methods in a class, whenever and *before* a method is run in that class?

In other words:

- I create `ConfigManager.edit_config()`.
- Whenever `ConfigManager.edit_config()` is called, another function `ConfigManager.get_config_file()` is run.
- `ConfigManager.get_config_file()` makes a value available to the method `ConfigManager.edit_config()`.
- And `ConfigManager.edit_config()` now runs, having access to the value given by `ConfigManager.get_config_file()`.

I expect to have many versions of `edit_config()` methods in `ConfigManager`, hence the desire to DRY my code.

Is there a recommended way of accomplishing something like this? Or should I just create a function to get the config fine, and manually call it each time?

Comment: Uhm… call `self.get_config_file()` in `edit_config()`? Explicit is better than implicit. What's the issue of doing this explicitly?

Comment: As I said, I feel as though there is a better way than running the function manually each time. I thought Python may have had a special class method, something like __init__(). If not then I can do it manually, I just wanted to explore other possibilities.

Comment: Do you have many many methods which would need to call `get_config_file`? Then I could understand that you may want to [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) your code… But if that method needs to run whenever you call `edit_config`, then it makes no difference whether it does so implicitly or explicitly.

Comment: Yeah, I will have very many methods in ConfigManager.

Comment: You may use decorator on your class to modify all known methods to do something before / after executing them, although I'd recommend rethinking your design twice before using it. Maybe you can have one private function that does everything you need and just expose your _very many methods_ to have convenient API. Still, without [MCVE] it's only pure guess.

Comment: I suppose it's about time I figured out how decorators work :D

Answer (score 2):

The natural way to have:

> `ConfigManager.get_config_file()` makes a value available to the method
>   `ConfigManager.edit_config()`.

is to have `get_config_file()` *return* that value.

Just call `get_config_file()` within `edit_config()`.

If there are going to be *many* versions of `edit_config()`, then a decorator might be the way to go:

```
def config_editor(func):
    def wrapped(self, *args, **kwargs):
        config_file = self.get_config_file()
        func(self, config_file, *args, **kwargs)
    return func

class ConfigManager
       .
       .
       .
    @config_editor
    def edit_config1(self, config_file, arg1):
           ...

    @config_editor
    def edit_config2(self, config_file, arg1, arg2):
           ...

ConfigManager mgr
mgr.edit_config1(arg1)
```

I don't actually like this:

Firstly, the declaration of `edit_config1` takes one more argument than the actual usage needs (because the decorator supplies the additional argument).

Secondly, it doesn't actually save all that much boiler plate over:

```
    def edit_config3(self, arg1):
        config_file = self.get_config_file()
```

In conclusion, I don't think the decorators save enough repetition to be worth it.

Comment: I know that this is possible, I just want by see if there were any other way to do it; rather than calling the same function over and over in what will likely become a very large number of methods in ConfigManager.

Comment: Ah!  So your problem is that there are *many* `edit_config` functions.  You need to [edit] your question to clarify that.

Answer (score 0):

Since you get something from disk, you open a file. So, you could use the class with the `with` "function" of python.

You should check the context managers. With that, you will be able to implement the functionality that you want each time that someone access the config file through the `__enter__` method and (if it is needed) implement the functionality for stop using the resource with the `__exit__` method.